# Sqoop row parse error

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop

I am getting the below error while doing Sqoop. It is trying to parse my entire record into a single timestamp field. Whats wrong here?

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Value '$d356aee0-09a3-4ddb-991e-61cae5758abd0000-00-00 00:00:002016-03-22 22:26:53$b4759fe2-aec6-11e1-8e54-00259060b612????????339-3661-6231-2d33-3038342d3431???
2015-09-30534-2d61-3966612d3437????016-08-17' can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetRow.getTimestampFast(ResultSetRow.java:1061)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.BufferRow.getTimestampFast(BufferRow.java:576)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getTimestampInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:6591)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getTimestamp(ResultSetImpl.java:6191)
    at org.apache.sqoop.lib.JdbcWritableBridge.readTimestamp(JdbcWritableBridge.java:111)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.JdbcWritableBridge.readTimestamp(JdbcWritableBridge.java:83)
    at QueryResult.readFields(QueryResult.java:199)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBRecordReader.nextKeyValue(DBRecordReader.java:246)
    ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a JDBC issue which can be handled by setting the property `zeroDateTimeBehavior` to `convertToNull`. so your sqoop command will look something like this

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://mysql-server:3306/database?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
```